# Finding rotation matrices for triangle corner given the rotation of adjacent faces

Tags: python, graphics, rotation, mesh

Given an original and a transformed triangle mesh as well as the rotation matrices for each face, how do I compute the rotations of the vertices?
Is it simply one of the rotation matrices from an adjacent face? If I'm not mistaken, the rotation isn't unique so this would be in favor for using one face rotation.

This is how the face transformation is computed.

```
# template is the positions of the vertices in the original mesh, 
# m respectively those of the transformed one.
# v denotes the triangle corners
origin = template[v[0], :].T
e1 = template[v[1], :].T - origin
e2 = template[v[2], :].T - origin
n = np.cross(e1, e2)
n = n / np.linalg.norm(n)
src = np.asarray([e1, e2, n]).T

to = m[v[0], :].T
t1 = m[v[1], :].T - to
t2 = m[v[2], :].T - to
tn = np.cross(t1, t2)
tn = tn / np.linalg.norm(tn)
tgt = np.asarray([t1, t2, tn]).T

# solve t @ src = tgt for t
t = (np.linalg.solve(src.T, tgt.T)).T 

r = t
u, _,v = np.linalg.svd(r)
r = u @ v
```

[image: The rotations of the vertices are supposed to compute the rigigity matrix.]

Comment: What do you expect this per-vertex rotation to do, i.e. how do you want to use it?

Comment: These rotations will be used to compute the angle between the transformations of two vertices as described in the image I added below my post.

Comment: Doesn't the paper explain how to calculate these rotations? If not, I would simply average the face rotations (in quaternion form), similar to averaging normals.

Comment: It doesn't. Thank you, I will do it this way then.